# How can I follow DRY principles with this challenge?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, dry, equality

I solved this exercise on jshero.com but I know the solution can be written more cleanly, I just don't know how.

Here are the directions:

Write a function addWithSurcharge that adds two amounts with surcharge. For each amount less than or equal to 10, the surcharge is 1. For each amount greater than 10 and less than or equal to 20, the surcharge is 2. For each amount greater than 20, the surcharge is 3.

This challenge also supposes that you use if...else if...else to solve the exercise, so I'm mainly concerned with simplification and readability, but I am also curious about ternaries. Here is my attempt which works,

```
function addWithSurcharge(num1, num2) {
    let surcharge = 0;
    if (num1 <= 10) {
        surcharge += 1;
    } else if (num1 > 10 && num1 <= 20) {
        surcharge += 2;
    } else {
        surcharge += 3;
    }
    
    if (num2 <= 10) {
        surcharge += 1;
    } else if (num2 > 10 && num2 <= 20) {
        surcharge += 2;
    } else {
        surcharge += 3;
    }
    
    return surcharge + num1 + num2;
}
```

Thank you,
much appreciated!

Comment: If your code works, and you just want help improving it, hit up https://codereview.stackexchange.com - Stackoverflow is for when [things don't work](/help/on-topic), and you've already searched around and tried to debug things yourself, but you're still stuck.

Comment: Put the repeated code in a function. Call the function passing `num1` and `num2` as parameters.

Comment: You don't need to test `num1 > 10`, since that's already assured by getting to the `else` block.

Comment: `surcharge = getSurcharge(num1) + getSurcharge(num2);`

Comment: Another perfectly valid question closed, congratulations. Following DRY principles is considered basic code quality, so this question is a SO material. Nobody said SO is just for things that don't work.